# Use cast for aggregate expression in pivot SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am using pivot in SQL Server and trying to use aggregate expressions using case:

```
select * 
from DailyIncome
pivot 
(
  SUM (Cast(IncomeAmount as numeric(10,2))) 
  for IncomeDay in ([MON],[TUE],[WED],[THU],[FRI],[SAT],[SUN])
) as AvgIncomePerDay
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

I also tried `ISNULL` instead of Cast but it doesn't work. Basically my `IncomeAmount` can also contain characters and I want to filter them out.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use functions like that with PIVOT, you'll need to use a subquery to perform the cast, then PIVOT the result. Similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select -- plus other columns you want in the final result
     IncomeDay,
     Value = Cast(IncomeAmount as numeric(10,2))
  from DailyIncome
) d
pivot 
(
  SUM (Value) 
  for IncomeDay in ([MON],[TUE],[WED],[THU],[FRI],[SAT],[SUN])
) as AvgIncomePerDay
```